# Oracle missing parenthesis when it isn't

Tags: sql, exists, oracle9i

```
SELECT company_name
FROM empl_company s
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    (SELECT city
     FROM empl_company
     WHERE company_name = 'Small Bank Corporation'
     )
     EXCEPT
    (SELECT city
     FROM empl_company k
     WHERE k.company_name = s.company_name
     ) 
);
```

I become an error
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
can enyone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Try to remove the parenthesises in the inner select. They are not needed for except and union (and migt be the cause for the problem)

Comment: 'missing right parenthesis' is a generic error mesage. Oracle tell it often

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EXCEPT` operator is called [`MINUS`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus) in Oracle;

```
select company_name
from empl_company s
where not exists (
  select city
  from empl_company
  where company_name = 'Small Bank Corporation'
  MINUS
  select city
  from empl_company k
  where k.company_name = s.company_name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

select company_name from emp1_company s where not exists(select city from emp1_company where company_name = 'Small Bank Corporation' and city in (select city FROM empl_company k WHERE k.company_name = s.company_name));